# Is the given set compact?

Tags: general-topology

> Let A={x$\in$$\mathbb{R}^3$ : $x_2^2$+$x_3^2$$\leq$$x_1$} and
>   B={x$\in$$\mathbb{R}^3$ : $x_1$$\leq$6}. Is A$\cap$B compact? Prove.

Now C=A$\cap$B={x$\in$$\mathbb{R}^3$ : $x_2^2$+$x_3^2$$\leq$6}. C is closed but not bounded. Thus it's not compact. Is that correct?

Comment: Is $(10,0,0)$ an element of $C?$ Does it satisfy $x_1\le 6?$ Your set $C$ is not correct.

Comment: The identity $A\cap B=\{x\in\Bbb R^3\,:\, x_2^2+x_3^2\le 6\}$ is false. Actually, $A\cap B\subsetneqq \{x\in\Bbb R^3\,:\, x_2^2+x_3^2\le 6\}$.

Answer (score 4):

Take any $(x_1,x_2,x_3)\in A\cap B$. Then we have $x_2^2+x_3^2\leq x_1\leq 6$ hence $x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2\leq 6^2+6=42$ so $A\cap B$ is bounded.

Consider a  Cauchy sequence of points $(x_1^{(n)},x_2^{(n)},x_3^{(n)})$ in $A\cap B$. We have that for each $n$, $(x_2^{(n)})^2+(x_3^{(n)})^2\leq x_1^{(n)}$ and $x_1^{(n)}\leq 6$.

Suppose this sequence converges to $(x_1,x_2,x_3)\in\mathbb R^3$. We want to check if $(x_1,x_2,x_3)\in A\cap B$.

In particular we know that $x_i^{(n)}\to x_i$ for each $i=1,2,3$.

From $(x_2^{(n)})^2+(x_3^{(n)})^2\leq x_1^{(n)}$ we allow $n\to\infty$ on both sides to get $x_2^2+x_3^2\leq x_1$ and from $x_1^{(n)}\leq 6$ we allow $n\to\infty$ to have $x_1\leq 6$.

Thus for $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ we have that $(x_1,x_2,x_3)\in A\cap B$, hence $A\cap B$ is closed.

As it is closed and bounded, by Heine Borel theorem, it is compact.

Comment: An alternative way to show that the intersection set is compact is by showing that both sets are closed.

Comment: It seems that Op had problem understanding that the set is bounded.

Answer (score 0):

Set $C$ will have correct definition $\{ x \in \mathbb{R}^3 :  x_1 \le 6 \; \text{and} \; x_2^2 + x^2_3 \le x_1 \}$.

Note that when $x_1 < 0$ the second condition is always false.

Answer (score 0):

Can one prove that the intersection set $A$$\cap$$B$ is closed by showing that $A^c$ and $B^c$ are open using properties of continuous functions?

Let $f_A$:$\mathbb{R}^3$ $\rightarrow$ $\mathbb{R}$ such that $f_A$($x_1$,$x_2$,$x_3$)=$x_2$$^2$+$x_3^2$-$x_1$. Obviously $f_A$ is continuous and $f^{-1}$(]0,$\infty$[)=$A^c=A^c\cap\mathbb{R}^3$. Thus, $A^c$ is open and $A$ closed.

Similarly for $B^c$...

Is that correct or wrong?

Comment: I think your reasoning is correct.

Comment: Good. I was about to give an answer like this. Note that if $f$ is continuous and $D$ is closed then $f^{-1}D$ is closed.